# What is a good software to use to generate a visualization of a graph G=(V,E)?

Tags: graph-theory, visualization

Are there any good softwares out there where I can input a list of edges and have it generate a graph visualization for me?

Comment: You might try [graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/).  I haven't used it in years, but it seems like it's being actively maintained, judging from activity on gitlab.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks. I'll check that out.

Comment: Mathematica has a lot of features for this. If your graph is small enough, Wolfram|Alpha might be able to do it for you.

Comment: @MarkS. I'll try Wolfram first. Do you mind showing me a quick example of how to do this on Wolfram? I actually haven't really used Wolfram in the past. Also, I'm using a mac in case that matters.

Comment: @MarkS. Oh never mind. That was pretty easy. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=draw+graph+with+edges+%281%2C2%29+%282%2C3%29